# identify cash on delivery is availble or not using zip/postal code check on product view page

Tags: product-view, cash-on-delivery

I want to add a textfield on "Product- view - page"

so that by entering zip/postal code, customer can check whether "cash on delivery " option is available

in their address or not.

I have some 500 zip/pin codes that support cash on delivery.

you can see demo example in the image.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance![image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of works need for above requirement.Basically  in magento there are few extension is:

http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/restrict-check-cod-payment-method-for-zip-pin-codes-1.html

Comment: hi @amit, did you used nextbits extension, seems its not working in frontend?